# Asymptotic normality is possible even when neither a mean nor a second moment exsit.

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_n\}$ be independent r.v. satisfying the Lindeberg conditon, set $s_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i)$. Define $\{\xi_n\}$ to be independent r.v. and independence with $\{X_n\}$. The distribution of $\{\xi_n\}$ is
$$P(\xi_n=0)=1-\frac1{n^2},~P(|\xi_n|>x)=\frac{1}{n^2}x^{-1}.$$

Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i+\xi_i}{s_n}\overset{d}\to \mathcal N(0,1).$$

How can we do to prove the conclusion? Do we need the distribution of $\{\xi_n\}$, or it just states that the random variables have no finite first and second moment?

Comment: The crucial remark is that, by Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\xi_n=0$ for every $n$ large enough, hence $\sum\limits_n|\xi_n|$ converges almost surely hence, since $s_n\to\infty$, $\frac1{s_n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i\to0$ almost surely, which should allow you to conclude.

Comment: @Did How do you conclude $\zeta_n=0$? BC lemma gives you that $\zeta_n\to0$ a.s. It is not mentioned $\zeta_n$ are integer valued.

Comment: Of course since $\zeta_n\to0$, it follows that as $s_n\to\infty$, $\dfrac{1}{s_n}\sum_{i=1}^n\zeta_i \to0$ a.s.

Comment: @LandonCarter ?? What is $\zeta_n$ in your comment? Anyway, one should apply BC to the events $[\xi_n\ne0]$.

Comment: @Did I got it, Thanks!

Comment: @LandonCarter Any explanation for your pair of comments above?

Comment: Yeah it is fine, Did. Your conclusion is stronger than mine. BTW $\zeta_n$ is just your zhi_n for want of better notation.